# Laravel Create Collection of a certain Model and add Objects manually

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I got a list of IDs and need to get a Collection (Let's say of the type "Book") and add Single Books to this Collection by Hand.

Example:

```
$ids = array(1,5,7,12);
$books = ???
foreach($ids as $id){
  $books->add(Book::find($id)); }
```

Or is there a easier way to get what I want?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write something like this I think:

```
$books = Book::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

`$books` will be a `Collection` containing all your books.